# Ordering Different Items among Different Groups

Tags: combinatorics

**Question 1)** Seven different gifts are to be distributed among 10 children. How many distinct results are possible if no child is to receive more than one gift?

The first gift can go to any of the 10 children, the second to any of the remaining 9 children,
and so on. Hence, there are 10 ⋅ 9 ⋅ 8 ⋅ ⋅ ⋅ 5 ⋅ 4 = 604,800 possibilities.

**Question 2)** In how many ways can 5 different fruits be distributed among four children? (Some children may get more than one fruit and some may get no fruits.)

Total number of ways of distributing 5 different fruits among 4 children = 4*4*4*4*4 = 4^5 ways.

**My Question:**
Why is the approach different in both questions? I would have imagined for Question 1 that the answer would have been 10^7. But in the problem, we are considering the fact that once a child has been chosen for a gift he/she is not available for the next gift. What gives for the difference in approach?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the fact that in question 2 you're told that more than one fruit can be given to any child and also that a child can even end up without getting a fruit. In the first case it hasn't been mentioned that you can give more than 1 gift to the same child. For question 2, if we're not allowed to give more than 1 fruit to a kid, then the solution is $5\times4\times3\times2\times1$ and the $5$ comes in because we can select the fruit that won't be given to any kid in $5$ ways.

Comment: Sorry just made an edit to Question 1. It is assumed that you cannot give each kid more than 1 gift.

Comment: I don't think it is the "at most 1 item per person" that is causing the problem.